# How can I check group membership when an user account is deleted ?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task which executes a PowerShell script when an user account is deleted from Active Directory. Is there a way to check the group membership of that user account ? I have tried with

```
 If ((Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOF) -ccontains $groupname)
    {
      //code
    }
```

but unfortunately, this didn't worked.(and is understandable why).

I was thinking at something as using a customized xml file for the creation of the scheduled task, but neither in this case, I don't know which value I have to query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

After a user account object is deleted, the SID will be removed from all groups the object was a member of. That is the reason why I personally prefer to disable user accounts, instead of deleting them.

However, if you enabled the **Active-Directory Recycle Bin** feature, you will be able to restore the user account object and all group membership information with it.

There are several ways to do so. I prefer to use the PowerShell. Here is an example:

```
 Get-ADObject -Filter {displayName -eq "Mary"} -IncludeDeletedObjects | Restore-ADObject
```

If you want to read more on the topic, please have a look at the [Active Directory Recycle Bin Step-by-Step Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392261%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

I also suggest you to enable said feature, if you haven't already.

The second option would be to fall back on your Active Directory backups, if your backup solution supports granular AD object restoration.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check anything at all *after* a user account is deleted, because then AD no longer has any information about it; your only option is to check group membership (or any other info you might need) *before* deleting the user account.

Comment: *"You can't check anything at all"* – I would not phrase it like that. While it's true for security groups and this particular question, ACLs where a user account SID was directly added, will keep the information.

Comment: I was talking about user attributes, which are completely lost after an user object is deleted (unless, as you noted in your answer, you can restore it somewhat, be it ADRB or backups). You are correct about orphaned ACLs, but they are quite useless in most situations.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood that part. That's right of course.